# A single DialogFragment for multiple dialogs?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can I use one single `DialogFragment` subclass to display multiple and different (but simple and similar) `AlertDialog`s?
I have many dialogs to display, and I am not sure if creating one class for each of them is necessary and good practice.

If I absolutely have to duplicate them: how do I organize them, name them?

Comment: Fragments are made to be reused so yes that is good practice to use a fragment in more than one spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use one single DialogFragment subclass to display multiple and
>   different (but simple and similar)

yes you can. In your subclass of `DialogFragment`, you could define the keys of the information you want to display, and using a simple factory method, to instantiate the DialogFragment, filling up the bundle containing the information. E.g.

```
  public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

      public static final String MESSAGE = "message";
      public static final String TITLE = "title"
      public static final String ICON_ID = "icon_id"

      public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message, int iconId) {
           Fragment f = new Fragment();
           Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
           // fill up b
           f.setArguments(b);
           return f;
      }

  }
```

When `onCreateView()`, is invoked, retrieve the bundle, with `getArguments`, and fill up your view

Comment: Changed `onCreteView` to `onCreateView()`

Comment: you are welcome. Don't forget to click on the checkmark